# Suspicious behavior by Google when verifying users via nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome

I'm building a user authentication system in Nodejs and use a confirmation email to verify a new account is real.

The user creates an account, which prompts him/her to check the email for a URL that he/she clicks to verify the account.

It works great, no issues.

What's unusual is that in testing, when I email myself (to simulate the new user process), and after I click the verify-URL, immediately afterward there are two subsequent connections to the endpoint. Upon inspection, it appears the source IPs belong to Google. What's even more interesting is that the user agent strings are random versions of Chrome.

Here's an example of the last sequence. The first one is the HTTP 200 request and the next two -- the HTTP 400s are Google. (I remove upon user verification the user's verification code from the database so that subsequence requests are HTTP 400s.)

```
162.158.78.180 - - [03/Jul/2020:20:35:40 +0000] "GET /v1/user/verify/95a546cf7ad448a18e7512ced322d96f HTTP/1.1" 200 70 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" "hidden.com" "72.191.192.163" "US" "en-US,en;q=0.9"
162.158.187.117 - - [03/Jul/2020:20:35:43 +0000] "GET /v1/user/verify/95a546cf7ad448a18e7512ced322d96f HTTP/1.1" 400 28 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "hidden.com" "74.125.210.22" "US" "en-US,en;q=0.9"
162.158.187.117 - - [03/Jul/2020:20:35:43 +0000] "GET /v1/user/verify/95a546cf7ad448a18e7512ced322d96f HTTP/1.1" 400 28 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36" "hidden.com" "74.125.210.8" "US" "en-US,en;q=0.9"
```

Now I'm using Cloudflare so the first IP address is a Cloudflare address but the second one you see is the real one [as reported by Cloudflare] ... I modified my "combined" log format in Nginx.

Anyhow, any idea what this is? Or why Google would be doing this?

It's just incredibly suspicious given the use of randomized user agent strings.

And one last note, if I inspect my console w/Chrome and go into the network tab before I click a verification link from my email, the 2 subsequent connections never come. It's like Google knows I'm monitoring ... this is just so incredibly odd that I had to ask the community. I'm thinking maybe this is an extension that's infected w/some kind of tracking, but how then do the IPs come back as Google?

New thread: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/234241/suspicious-behavior-by-google-when-verifying-users-via-nodejs?noredirect=1#comment479497_234241

Comment: This is not a development question, probably should have been posted over on superUser https://superuser.com/ . Or infoSec https://security.stackexchange.com/ - They will be the better audience.

Comment: If there is a dev issue your concerned about, then feel free to add it.

Comment: Okay, I posted the question there. We can close it here if you like.

Comment: New thread: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/234241/suspicious-behavior-by-google-when-verifying-users-via-nodejs?noredirect=1#comment479497_234241

Answer (score 0):

this is going to sound weird but i started having the same problem this week and i’ve been going legitimately crazy trying to figure out what’s causing it.  is your desktop a windows machine?  if so is it running the adobe update service?  (adobeupdateservice.exe)

i have been killing processes and shutting off chrome extensions one by one and it finally stopped doing this after i killed the adobe services.  i have two computers with mostly identical software installs and only one will trigger this in chrome - one difference is that the computer triggering these “cache.google.com” requests has a much newer adobeupdateservice from like two weeks ago

i have been throwing requests at it all day now and finally it’s stopped sending phantom followup requests from weird IPs

Comment: No, my os is macOS. I do run the Adobe update service, but I don't think this is the issue as this activity only occurs when using Chrome. If I use Firefox, the second two connections don't happen.

Comment: This is crazy though Tony! I think maybe Google is checking to ensure the links aren't malicious as I'm emailing myself and then clicking from an email so it'd make sense Google would check. But why then do it twice and use bogus user agent strings?

Comment: Crazy, imagine there was a place that knew what they were talking about : https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: New thread: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/234241/suspicious-behavior-by-google-when-verifying-users-via-nodejs?noredirect=1#comment479497_234241